# Is it the same to insert into tables from query as from table using VBA?

Tags: vba, insert

so this is my code below it works just fine when selecting from a table :

```
Private Sub cmdStart_Click()
Dim strSql1 As String
Dim strSql2 As String
Dim strSql3 As String
Dim strSql4 As String
Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set dbs = CurrentDb

strSql1 = "insert into qoyod_details (qaed_num,f_year,qaed_date,l_value,Hesab_code) " & _
"select " & Forms("qoyod").qaed_num & " , " & Forms("qoyod").f_year & " , format('" & Forms("qoyod").qaed_date & "' , 'dd/mm/yyyy') , sum(sale_bill_total), 167 " & _
"from sale_bill where sale_bill_date between  format( '" & Me.cmbQFrom & "' ,'mm/dd/yyyy') and format( '" & Me.cmbQTo & "' ,'mm/dd/yyyy') and sale_bill_type = 1 "
dbs.Execute strSql1
```

but when I try to select from a query it just wont work
is there something am doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check if you're able to insert data directly/manually into the query `qoyod_details`

Comment: qoyod_details is a table not a query

Comment: Can you share the error message you are getting and the data types of the table fields?

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to enclose your data correctly:

- numbers need no enclosure: `200`
- string need to be enclosed with `'` or `"`: `'String'` or `"String"`
- Dates need to be enclosed with `#`: `#2020-11-22#`

When concatenating strings to an SQL string I usually use the single quotes `'`

So just guessing on what the field data types are, here is what you SQL string should look like:

```
strSql1 = "insert into qoyod_details (qaed_num,f_year,qaed_date,l_value,Hesab_code) " & _
"select " & Forms("qoyod").qaed_num & " , " & Forms("qoyod").f_year & " , #" & format(Forms("qoyod").qaed_date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#, sum(sale_bill_total) , 167 " & _
"from sale_bill where sale_bill_date between #" & format( Me.cmbQFrom, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "# and #" & format(Me.cmbQTo, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "# and sale_bill_type = 1"

dbs.Execute strSql1
```

To simplify date conversion use the ISO format `yyyy-mm-dd`, this will prevent any accidental switching between the day and month in certain configurations.

If you're still getting an error, then try printing the result to the Immediate Window like this for troubleshooting:

```
Debug.Print strSql1

dbs.Execute strSql1
```

before trying to execute the string.